# How can I use RoleForEach() validation method for List Type Entity?

Tags: c#

I have multiple input for `MobileNo`. View Model:

```
   public class CompanyAccountViewModel
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public float Interval { get; set; }
        public List<string> MobileNo { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
   <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
            <span class="add-new-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="add_mobile"> </span>

            @for (var i = 0; i < TotalMobiles; i++)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MobileNo[i], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "mobile_no" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo[i], "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            }

        </div>
    </div>
```

And validation Rule is:

```
RuleFor(x => x.MobileNo).Must(IsMobileNoUnique).WithMessage("This Mobile Number Already Exist");
```

***IsMobileNoUnique*** method:

```
public bool IsMobileNoUnique(ICollection<string> mobileNo)
{
    IList<Domain.Contacts.Mobile> mobiles = _powerSupplyDBContext.Mobiles.Where(w => mobileNo.Contains(w.MobileNo)).ToList();

    if (mobiles.Any())
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

This validation is commonly applied, i.e: if I want to input 3 mobile number from which 2 inputs are duplicate and 1 is unique. Now I am getting validation error with a generic format for 3 inputs. But I want to show more specific error message, i.e: if 1st and 3rd input are duplicate error will be shown for these two inputs keeping the rest as it was. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

why you dont just use the

```
get {}
```

statement for validation?

I am sorry for posting it as answer, but I cant comment yet, 1 reputation off.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I modified as follows:

```
RuleForEach(x => x.MobileNo).Must(IsMobileNoUnique).WithMessage("This Mobile Number Already Exist");
```

and ***IsMobileNoUnique***

```
   public bool IsMobileNoUnique(string mobileNo)
        {
           Domain.Contacts.Mobile mobiles = _powerSupplyDBContext.Mobiles.Where(m=>m.MobileNo == mobileNo).FirstOrDefault();

            if (mobiles==null)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```